# Installing doxygen plugin for Qt creator

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plugins, qt-creator, doxygen

I'm trying to install doxygen plugin for Qt Creator (http://dev.kofee.org/), but when I start Qt Creater I get the following errors

```
Could not resolve dependency 'Core(2.8.1)'
Could not resolve dependency 'CppEditor(2.8.1)'
Could not resolve dependency 'CppTools(2.8.1)'
Could not resolve dependency 'Locator(2.8.1)'
Could not resolve dependency 'ProjectExplorer(2.8.1)'
Could not resolve dependency 'TextEditor(2.8.1)'
```

I can't find anything about those errors in Google. Does anybody know how to solve it or probably anyone can suggest other plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Answering an old question to document my findings on this issue.

From the Qt Creator Plugin wiki at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Creator_Plug-in_Gallery

Qt Creator uses "the approach of adding all the functionality by plugins" and the items mentioned in the error messages are the "plugins" that deliver standard functionality.

Which matches the list of plugins that the doxygen plugin says it depends on at http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/repository/entry/trunk/Doxygen.pluginspec

```
<dependencyList>
    <dependency name="Core" version="3.1.0" compatVersion="3.1.0_1"/>
    <dependency name="CppEditor" version="3.1.0" compatVersion="3.1.0_1"/>
    <dependency name="CppTools" version="3.1.0" compatVersion="3.1.0_1"/>
    <dependency name="ProjectExplorer" version="3.1.0" compatVersion="3.1.0_1"/>
    <dependency name="TextEditor" version="3.1.0" compatVersion="3.1.0_1"/>
</dependencyList>
```

So, in summary, it looks like you are trying to install a version of the plugin that is built for a different version of QtCreator.

There is a list of all the different versions of this plugin at http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/files and the file name includes the version of QtCreator that it is built for.

E.g. qtcreator-doxygen-0.3.9-**qtcreator-3.1.x**-linux-x86_64.tar.gz